# How do I remove footprints after sealing travertine tile?

Tags: sealing, travertine

It looks like I made a pretty basic mistake and stepped into some of the sealant after sealing my travertine tiles last night.Today you can see footprints in the sealant.

What is the best way to remove these? Do I need to strip the sealant or can I reseal the tiles?